# Yolov8 object tracking No module names lap

Tags: python, pip, yolov8

Actually I was using yolov8 track function and got this error

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('best.pt')
results = model.track(source="1.mp4", conf=0.3)
```

```
pip install lap
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pencv-python (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Collecting lap
  Using cached lap-0.4.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: lap
  Building wheel for lap (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [50 lines of output]
      Partial import of lap during the build process.
      C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5n1k5a80\lap_5ee53496753c49158b96af0ae0829a26\setup.py:223: DeprecationWarning:        

        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html


        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
      Generating cython files
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      INFO: unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      INFO: unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      INFO: build_src
      INFO: building extension "lap._lapjv" sources
      INFO: building data_files sources
      INFO: build_src: building npy-pkg config files
      C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
              Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer, pypa/build or
              other standards-based tools.

              See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        self.initialize_options()
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lap
      copying lap\lapmod.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lap
      copying lap\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lap
      running build_ext
      INFO: No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      INFO: customize MSVCCompiler
      INFO: customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1077] : testing flags (/O2)
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      INFO: CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[857] : write cache to path -> C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5n1k5a80\lap_5ee53496753c49158b96af0ae0829a26\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
      [end of output]



  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lap
  Running setup.py clean for lap
Failed to build lap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lap, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am currently facing an error when attempting to run the command "pip install lap." Despite my efforts to rectify the issue, which involved upgrading setuptools to the latest version and installing CMake, I have not been able to resolve the error. This has left me in a bit of a quandary, as I am unable to proceed further without successfully installing the "lap" package. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or advice you can provide to help me troubleshoot and overcome this error. Your expertise in this matter would be invaluable to me. Thank you in advance for your support.

What I did?

upgraded setuptool

Downloaded VS build c++

installing specific version of lap

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out once before. But I found the package somewhere and reposted it here:
https://github.com/Adnedvid/Lap-pkg-for-YOLO.git

Just install into site-packages in your environment. Has worked for me between multiple machines for python 3.8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).